# C2C Employment considered self employed for Fannie / Freddie?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, self-employment

I was recently offered a job after interviewing. They offered either w2 or corp 2 corp work. I chose corp to corp and created an LLC and signed a year long renewable contract as a single member LLC taxed as S-corp meaning I payroll myself. They drug tested / background checked and provided a laptop, a bit of training and guidelines.

I've been in the same industry since 2017, have incrementally made more money and gained more seniority by title.

Recently I applied for a Freddie / Fannie loan. They said I was self employed.

Somehow I can't imagine this is true. I feel like there must be an exception for this circumstance. If I hired another developer to work in my place my company would terminate our relationship. They hired me and and offered either c2c or w2.

Either way, if Freddie / Fannie's only measure is if I own 25% or more of the company and there are no exceptions for this case is it okay to assign a family member 75% of the company and reapply?

Thanks

Comment: Are you in a situation where you cannot get the loan because you are self employed? Simply because you elected to do C2C instead of W2?

Answer (score 3):

> Recently I applied for a Freddie / Fannie loan. They said I was self
> employed.
>
> Somehow I can't imagine this is true. I feel like there must be an
> exception for this circumstance.

By self employed they mean that you are not a W-2 employee. You setup a C2C relationship, and formed a company. You decide how much of the corporate income is your salary. They have to do a lot more analysis to determine what your income really is. They can't look at the W-2 from last year, and recent pay stubs.

Self employed people always have more hoops to jump through to get loans.

Comment: Exactly.  "**I payroll myself** makes it about a clear as can be that OP is self-employed.

Comment: But think about it logically, my company hired me, employs me and asked for c2c to avoid benefits. I don't go out and get clients. They are my sole client. If I were to take on another client I would be let go. This isn't self employment in the traditional sense at all.

Comment: You are your own company. They are your customer/client.

Comment: I'll give give 75% ownership to someone else then. Problem solved.

Comment: OP is actually a W-2 employee. (Has to be.)  But, apparently it doesn't matter. "Self employed" to them just means 25% or more ownership of the company.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bizarre situation. I understand legally self employed but any reasonable person would look at my situation and the existing guidelines and say I wasn't self employed in the traditional sense. Self-employment is a problem for them because they have to go out and get clients and do the work and rinse and repeat. It's not stable. Where as my situation, I have the contract. They expect no one else to do it. It's valid for a year. Sad the regulations don't see this.